# Inheriting from a template class, Types are declared in child class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, types

I want to have a template parent class (virtual). A child class inherits from the parent and defines the type within itself.

```cpp
// PARENT
template <typename A, typename B>
class Parent 
{
public:
    Parent();
    virtual ~Parent();
    // ...
};

// CHILD
class Child : public Parent<SomeStruct , AnotherStruct>
{
public:
    struct SomeStruct 
    {/*...*/};

    struct AnotherStruct
    {/*...*/};

    Child();
    ~Child();
    // ...
};
```

Obvisouly, the compiler will complain about the not yet defined "SomeStruct". The question is how to achieve something similar. A easy way would be to define the structs outside the class but that would make things so much uglier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a chicken and egg situation. The compiler *needs* to see the structs declared so it can instantiate Parent.

You can try something like:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
class Parent 
{
public:
    Parent();
    virtual ~Parent();
    // ...
};

// CHILD
class ChildBase
{
    public:
    struct SomeStruct 
    {/*...*/};

    struct AnotherStruct
    {/*...*/};
};

class Child : public ChildBase, public Parent<ChildBase::SomeStruct, ChildBase::AnotherStruct>
{
public:
    using ChildBase::SomeStruct;
    using ChildBase::AnotherStruct;

    Child();
    ~Child();
    // ...
};
```

This goes the multiple inheritance route. Alternatively you can put the struct declarations in a namespace instead of a base class which doesn't leave them sitting in the global namespace.

Both ways are not quite what you wanted but don't pollute the global namespace and leave the types visible on Child if you want Child::SomeStruct kind of syntax.

Comment: Looks better then declaring both structs in global namespace. :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do what you are trying.

You can forward declare a class but you cannot forward declare a nested class. You'll have to rethink your design.

Comment: thanks, will have to declare the structs outside of the class then. :/

Answer (score 1):

There is one solution that might help you.
It is not exactly like you are doing but it's achieving the same thing.
It is done using the "Policy" idom
Take a look at this:

```
// PARENT
template <typename Policy>
struct Parent : Policy {
    Parent();
    virtual ~Parent();
    // ...
};

// CHILD POLICY
struct ChildPolicy {
    struct SomeStruct 
    {/*...*/};

    struct AnotherStruct
    {/*...*/};
}

// CHILD
struct Child : public Parent<ChildPolicy> {
    Child();
    ~Child();

    // Here you can use your two types 
    // ...
};
```

Alternatively, if the types you are using in Child have a well established type name across all child of that sort, you can declare the parent like this:

```
template <typename Policy>
struct Parent {

    using typename Policy::SomeStruct;
    using typename Policy::AnotherStruct;

    Parent();
    virtual ~Parent();
    // ...
};
```

I strongly recommend the second solution for the parent